# get all iphone Contact in ios Application with iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, contacts, abaddressbook

I am developing an application in which I want to get all contacts from my iphone including detail (First Name, Last Name, Email and Mobile Number). The deployment target of application is iOS 7 and later.

I had tried a below code but its not working at all.

> My code is here

```
__block NSMutableArray *myContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    CFErrorRef error = NULL;
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

    __block BOOL userDidGrantAddressBookAccess;
    CFErrorRef addressBookError = NULL;

    if ( ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined ||
        ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized )
    {
        addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &addressBookError);
        dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error)
        {
            userDidGrantAddressBookAccess = granted;
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
            if (addressBook!=nil)
            {
                NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

                NSUInteger i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i<[allContacts count]; i++)
                {
                                        ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
                    NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);


                    [myContacts addObject:firstName];
                }
                CFRelease(addressBook);

            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"Error");

            }
        });
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    }
    else
    {
        if ( ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
            ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
        {
            NSLog(@"denied");
            // Display an error.
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", myContacts);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost completely correct. You simply need to print out your `myContacts` array in the completion block of your Address Book request.

I've made some code changes for you:

```
__block NSMutableArray *myContacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);

__block BOOL userDidGrantAddressBookAccess;
CFErrorRef addressBookError = NULL;

if ( ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined ||
    ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized )
{
    addressBook = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, &addressBookError);
    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);
    ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(addressBook, ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
     userDidGrantAddressBookAccess = granted;
     dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
     if (addressBook!=nil)
     {
         NSArray *allContacts = (__bridge_transfer NSArray*)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

         NSUInteger i = 0;
         for (i = 0; i<[allContacts count]; i++)
         {
             ABRecordRef contactPerson = (__bridge ABRecordRef)allContacts[i];
             NSString *firstName = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(contactPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);

             // you need to do a nil check before adding a firstName to the array
             //
             // some contacts won't have first names, after all
             if([firstName length] > 0)
             {
                 [myContacts addObject:firstName];
             }
         }
         CFRelease(addressBook);
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Error");
     }

     // *** HERE is where to print out the myContacts array***
     NSLog(@"addresses are %@", myContacts);
    });
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
}
else
{
    if ( ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
        ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted )
    {
        NSLog(@"denied");
        // Display an error.
    }
}

// don't NSLog here, as myContacts array likey won't be filled out here...
// print it out in the completion block instead
// NSLog(@"%@", myContacts);
```

B.T.W., if your code is only going to run on iOS 9 and newer, consider using CNContactStore instead, as the AddressBook API's are deprecated and could eventually be removed from iOS.

Comment: Please update you code for getting last name, email and image.

Comment: Now that you see what I am doing, could you do that?

Comment: Is this code works perfectly for ios 9 ? Or I need to check that that the os is iOS 9 or later by code ?

Comment: try a different question & separate post, since I've already answered this one :-)